# could not set the column width to zero i.e. not made column invisible

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecolumn

I am trying to make one column from `JTable`, invisible by setting width to zero but it could not happen and it remain visible to width = 15. Here is code -

```
public void restoreColumnWithWidth(int column, int width) {
        try {
            TableColumn tableColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column);
            table.getTableHeader().setResizingColumn(tableColumn);
            tableColumn.setWidth(width);
            tableColumn.setMaxWidth(width);
            tableColumn.setMinWidth(width);
            tableColumn.setPreferredWidth(width);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
```

What is wrong with the code ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- not, never to remove `TableColumn` from `TableModel`, this is wrong suggestion, instead of to use built-in method [JTable#removeColumn(TableColumn aColumn)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#removeColumn%28javax.swing.table.TableColumn%29),
- notice, this method remove column only from View, in the model is removed column still presents, and you can revert that, visible the removed column by using [JTable#addColumn(TableColumn aColumn)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#addColumn%28javax.swing.table.TableColumn%29)

EDIT

[image][image][image][image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Stack;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

public class TableRowHeight {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("p*s*s*s*s*t*t");
    private String[] columnNames = {"one", "two", "Playing with", "four", "five",};
    private String[][] data = {
        {"aaaaaa", "bbbbbb", "cccccc", "dddddd", "eeeeeee",},
        {"bbbbbb", "cccccc", "dddddd", "eeeeeee", "aaaaaa",},
        {"cccccc", "dddddd", "eeeeeee", "aaaaaa", "bbbbbb",},
        {"dddddd", "eeeeeee", "aaaaaa", "bbbbbb", "cccccc",},
        {"eeeeeee", "aaaaaa", "bbbbbb", "cccccc", "dddddd",}};
    private JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames));
    private TableColumnModel tcm = table.getColumnModel();
    private Stack<TableColumn> colDeleted = new Stack<TableColumn>();
    private JButton restoreButton = new JButton("Restore Column Size");
    private JButton hideButton = new JButton("Set Column Size to Zero");
    private JButton deleteButton = new JButton("Delete Column");
    private JButton addButton = new JButton("Restore Column");

    public TableRowHeight() {
        table.setRowMargin(4);
        table.setRowHeight(30);
        table.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD + Font.PLAIN, 20));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        for (int i = 0; i < (tcm.getColumnCount()); i++) {
            tcm.getColumn(i).setPreferredWidth(100);
        }
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        restoreButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                tcm.getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(100);
            }
        });
        hideButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                tcm.getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(000);
            }
        });
        deleteButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (table.getColumnCount() > 0) {
                    TableColumn colToDelete = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(table.getColumnCount() - 1);
                    table.removeColumn(colToDelete);
                    table.validate();
                    colDeleted.push(colToDelete);
                    addButton.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    deleteButton.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });
        addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (colDeleted.size() > 0) {
                    table.addColumn(colDeleted.pop());
                    table.validate();
                    deleteButton.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    addButton.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        btnPanel.add(hideButton);
        btnPanel.add(restoreButton);
        btnPanel.add(deleteButton);
        btnPanel.add(addButton);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(150, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                TableRowHeight frame = new TableRowHeight();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

EDIT2

you have to check too

```
JTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
JTable.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. mKorbel but can you please look into my code. Is any thing wrong with that? Setting width to zero must work.

Comment: @Ashish Pancholi please see my edit, did we talking about the same :-)

Comment: Thanks Mr. mKorbel. It's now clear after seeing your sample code. Case Solved.

Comment: @Ashish Pancholi you're welcome, glad to help you +1 for nice thread

Answer (score 4):

If it should be removed, and not just hidden: Remove it from the table-model.
If it only should be hidden and later shown, you can remove the TableColumn from the TableColumnModel

Making the column height 0 is a bit bogus.