# Exclude a column from JTable when sorting

Tags: java, sorting, jtable

So I basically do not want the second column to show up when I sort in my JTable or vice-versa. A picture is worth a thousands words so here is a picture to show you what I mean. http://i48.tinypic.com/2rzpfe9.jpg
So as you can see when I search for the word "apple" in my JTable, the second column is still there which it shouldn't be because the first column has the word "apple" in it and not the second column. So how can I make it that that the other column don't show up or vice-versa?

**EDIT :** I have  edited the code below to match what MadProgrammer said but it still isn't working right. New pic http://i48.tinypic.com/2rzpfe9.jpg
The text this time is gone but the column remains. What am I doing wrong this time?

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Component;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    import javax.swing.JTable;
    import javax.swing.JTextArea;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import javax.swing.RowFilter;
    import javax.swing.UIManager;
    import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
    import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
    import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
    import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
    import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
    import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class sorter extends JFrame {
/**
     * 
     */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public sorter() {
initComponents();
panel.setLayout(null);
search.setBounds(30,10,400,25);
search_button.setBounds(430,10,30,25);
}
public class FilterEntry extends RowFilter.Entry<TableModel, Integer> {

    private final TableModel model;
    private final Object value;
    private final int rowIndex;

    public FilterEntry(TableModel model, Object value, int rowIndex) {

        this.model = model;
        this.value = value;
        this.rowIndex = rowIndex;

    }

    @Override
    public TableModel getModel() {

        return model;

    }

    @Override
    public int getValueCount() {

        return getModel().getColumnCount();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getValue(int index) {

        return value;

    }

    @Override
    public Integer getIdentifier() {

        return rowIndex;

    }

}


private void initComponents() {
panel = new JPanel();
logo = new JLabel();
pane = new JScrollPane();
search = new JTextField();
search_button = new JButton();
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 204));
setResizable(false);
panel.setBackground(new Color(51, 51, 51));
panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(290, 40));
javax.swing.GroupLayout panelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panel);
panel.setLayout(panelLayout);
panelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
.addGroup(panelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
.addGap(198, 198, 198)
.addComponent(logo)
.addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
);
panelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
.addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, panelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
.addContainerGap(0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
.addComponent(logo)
.addContainerGap())
);
search.setText("");
search.setToolTipText("");
search.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.LOWERED));
search.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(30, 15));
search_button.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/search.JPG"))); // NOI18N
search_button.setAlignmentY(0.0F);
search_button.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
search_button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
search_button.setIconTextGap(1);
search_button.setMargin(new java.awt.Insets(1, 4, 1, 4));
search_button.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(5, 30));
search_button.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(5, 30));
search_button.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(30, 20));
javax.swing.GroupLayout panelLayout1 = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panel);
panel.setLayout(panelLayout1);
panelLayout1.setHorizontalGroup(
panelLayout1.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
.addGroup(panelLayout1.createSequentialGroup()
.addGroup(panelLayout1.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
.addGroup(panelLayout1.createSequentialGroup()
.addGap(25, 25, 25)
.addComponent(search, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 400, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
.addGap(0, 0, 0)
.addComponent(search_button, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
.addGroup(panelLayout1.createSequentialGroup()
.addGap(174, 174, 174)
.addComponent(logo)))
.addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
);
panelLayout1.setVerticalGroup(
panelLayout1.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
.addGroup(panelLayout1.createSequentialGroup()
.addGap(5, 5, 5)
.addComponent(logo)
.addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
.addGroup(panelLayout1.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
.addComponent(search, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
.addComponent(search_button, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, Short.MAX_VALUE))
.addContainerGap())
);
ImageIcon Icon1 = getImage("lemon.jpg");
ImageIcon Icon2 = getImage("az.jpg");
ImageIcon Icon3 = getImage("aaa.jpg");
ImageIcon Icon4 = getImage("ba.jpg");
ImageIcon Icon5 = getImage("bas.jpg");
ImageIcon Icon6 = getImage("cookies.jpg");
String[] columnNames = {"A", "Section 1","B", "Section 2"};
Object[][] data =
{
{Icon1, "Lemon", Icon2, "Grapes"},
{Icon3, "Apple", Icon4, "Banana"},
{Icon5, "Orange", Icon6, "Cookies"},
};
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
JTable table = new JTable(model)
{
/**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public Class getColumnClass(int column)
{
return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
}
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
return false;
}
};
class MultiLineCellRenderer extends JTextArea implements TableCellRenderer {
/**
     * 
     */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public MultiLineCellRenderer() {
setLineWrap(true);
setWrapStyleWord(true);
setOpaque(true);
}


public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
RowFilter rowFilter = ((TableRowSorter) table.getRowSorter()).getRowFilter();
if (rowFilter != null) {
if (!rowFilter.include(new FilterEntry(table.getModel(), value, row))) {
value = null;
}         
} else {
setForeground(table.getForeground());
setBackground(table.getBackground());
}
setFont(table.getFont());
if (hasFocus) {
setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("Table.focusCellHighlightBorder"));
if (table.isCellEditable(row, column)) {
setForeground(UIManager.getColor("Table.focusCellForeground"));
setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Table.focusCellBackground"));
}
} else {
setBorder(new EmptyBorder(1, 2, 1, 2));
}
setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
return this;
}
}


// Sorter Code. 
table = new JTable(model);
final TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);

table.setRowSorter(sorter);
search_button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
String text = search.getText();
if (text.length() == 0) {
sorter.setRowFilter(null);
} else {
sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)"+ text));
}
}
});
// sorter code ends here.



table.setRowHeight(50);
pane.setViewportView(table);
table.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 204));
table.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, new MultiLineCellRenderer());

table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new MultiLineCellRenderer());
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(new MultiLineCellRenderer());

table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setResizable(false);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setResizable(false);
table.setFocusable(false);
table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
int vColIndex = 0;
TableColumn col = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(vColIndex);
int width = 33;
col.setPreferredWidth(width);
int vColIndex1 = 1;
TableColumn col1 = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(vColIndex1);
int width1 = 216;
col1.setPreferredWidth(width1);
int vColIndex11 = 2;
TableColumn col11 = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(vColIndex11);
int width11 = 33;
col11.setPreferredWidth(width11);
int vColIndex111 = 3;
TableColumn col111 = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(vColIndex111);
int width111 = 216;
col111.setPreferredWidth(width111);
javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
layout.setHorizontalGroup(
layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
.addComponent(panel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 500, Short.MAX_VALUE)
.addComponent(pane)
);
layout.setVerticalGroup(
layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
.addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
.addComponent(panel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
.addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
.addComponent(pane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 250, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
.addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
.addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
);
pack();
}
private ImageIcon getImage(String path)
{
java.net.URL url = getClass().getResource(path);
if (url != null)
return (new ImageIcon(url));
else
{
System.out.println(url);
return null;
}
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
try {
for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
break;
}
}
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(sorter.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (InstantiationException ex) {
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(sorter.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(sorter.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(sorter.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
new sorter().setVisible(true);
}
});
}
private JLabel logo;
private JScrollPane pane;
private JPanel panel;
private JTextField search;
private JButton search_button;
}
```

Comment: See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10089138/230513) that demonstrates show/hide and add/remove for columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify the renderer so that it only displays the value if it matches the filter.

Given the fact that you are using the `TableRowSorter` makes it easier.

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

    RowFilter rowFilter = ((TableRowSorter) table.getRowSorter()).getRowFilter();
    if (rowFilter != null) {

        if (!rowFilter.include(new FilterEntry(table.getModel(), value, row))) {

            value = null;

        }

    }

    // The rest of the code...

}
```

Now, you're going to need to implement your own `FilterEntry` :P

```
public class FilterEntry extends RowFilter.Entry<TableModel, Integer> {

    private final TableModel model;
    private final Object value;
    private final int rowIndex;

    public FilterEntry(TableModel model, Object value, int rowIndex) {

        this.model = model;
        this.value = value;
        this.rowIndex = rowIndex;

    }

    @Override
    public TableModel getModel() {

        return model;

    }

    @Override
    public int getValueCount() {

        return getModel().getColumnCount();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getValue(int index) {

        return value;

    }

    @Override
    public Integer getIdentifier() {

        return rowIndex;

    }

}
```

And in order to get the example to work, I had to add

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new MultiLineCellRenderer());
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(new MultiLineCellRenderer());
```

Under where you set the default cell renderer

**UPDATED with Mutable column model**

The larger problem you face is having the ability to turn columns on and off.  Trashgod provided an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088853/could-not-set-the-column-width-to-zero-i-e-not-made-column-invisible/10089138#10089138) of this and I've included a sample model.

The next thing you need to do, is every time the filter changes, you need to run through the entire model and decide what should be include and what shouldn't.

This is how I achieved it...

First, you need to supply your own `ColumnModel`

```
// Changing the column model effects the data model as well...
TableModel model = table.getModel();
table.setColumnModel(new MutableColumnModel());
table.setModel(model);
```

In you action listener, after you apply the filter, you will need to call `updateColumns`

```
protected void updateColumns() {

    RowFilter rowFilter = ((TableRowSorter) tblSearch.getRowSorter()).getRowFilter();

    MutableTableColumnModel columnModel = (MutableTableColumnModel) tblSearch.getColumnModel();
    // Want to reset the columns, otherwise we run into problems doing the value
    // lookup, as the table doesn't think it exists.
    // You might be able to get around it with this instead, but we need
    // to rest the view any way...
    // columnModel.getColumnByModelIndex(col);
    columnModel.setColumnVisible(0, true);
    columnModel.setColumnVisible(1, true);
    columnModel.setColumnVisible(2, true);
    columnModel.setColumnVisible(3, true);

    if (rowFilter != null) {

        Map<Integer, Boolean> mapColumns = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>(tblSearch.getColumnCount());
        for (int row = 0; row < tblSearch.getRowCount(); row++) {

            boolean include = includeValue(row, 1, rowFilter);
            mapColumns.put(0, include);
            mapColumns.put(1, include);

            include = includeValue(row, 3, rowFilter);
            mapColumns.put(2, include);
            mapColumns.put(3, include);

        }

        for (Integer col : mapColumns.keySet()) {

            columnModel.setColumnVisible(col, mapColumns.get(col));

        }

    }

}

protected boolean includeValue(int row, int col, RowFilter filter) {

    Object value = tblSearch.getValueAt(row, col);

    boolean include = filter.include(new FilterEntry(tblSearch.getModel(), value, row));

    System.out.println("include " + value + "; include = " + include);

    return include;

}
```

The `MutableColumnModel`

```
public class MutableTableColumnModel extends DefaultTableColumnModel {

    private List<TableColumn> allTableColumns;

    public MutableTableColumnModel() {

        allTableColumns = new ArrayList<TableColumn>(10);

    }

    public void setColumnVisible(int index, boolean visible) {

        setColumnVisible(getColumnByModelIndex(index), visible);

    }

    /**
     * Sets the visibility of the specified TableColumn.
     * The call is ignored if the TableColumn is not found in this column model
     * or its visibility status did not change.
     * <p>
     *
     * @param aColumn        the column to show/hide
     * @param visible its new visibility status
     */
    // listeners will receive columnAdded()/columnRemoved() event
    public void setColumnVisible(TableColumn column, boolean visible) {

        if (column != null) {

            if (!visible) {

                if (isColumnVisible(column)) {

                    super.removeColumn(column);

                }

            } else {

                // find the visible index of the column:
                // iterate through both collections of visible and all columns, counting
                // visible columns up to the one that's about to be shown again
                int noVisibleColumns = tableColumns.size();
                int noInvisibleColumns = allTableColumns.size();
                int visibleIndex = 0;

                for (int invisibleIndex = 0; invisibleIndex < noInvisibleColumns; ++invisibleIndex) {
                    TableColumn visibleColumn = (visibleIndex < noVisibleColumns ? (TableColumn) tableColumns.get(visibleIndex) : null);
                    TableColumn testColumn = (TableColumn) allTableColumns.get(invisibleIndex);

                    if (testColumn == column) {
                        if (visibleColumn != column) {
                            super.addColumn(column);
                            super.moveColumn(tableColumns.size() - 1, visibleIndex);
                        }
                        return; // ####################
                    }
                    if (testColumn == visibleColumn) {
                        ++visibleIndex;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    /**
     * Makes all columns in this model visible
     */
    public void showAllColumns() {
        int noColumns = allTableColumns.size();

        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < noColumns; ++columnIndex) {
            TableColumn visibleColumn = (columnIndex < tableColumns.size() ? (TableColumn) tableColumns.get(columnIndex) : null);
            TableColumn invisibleColumn = (TableColumn) allTableColumns.get(columnIndex);

            if (visibleColumn != invisibleColumn) {
                super.addColumn(invisibleColumn);
                super.moveColumn(tableColumns.size() - 1, columnIndex);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Maps the index of the column in the table model at
     * <code>modelColumnIndex</code> to the TableColumn object.
     * There may me multiple TableColumn objects showing the same model column, though this is uncommon.
     * This method will always return the first visible or else the first invisible column with the specified index.
     * @param modelColumnIndex index of column in table model
     * @return table column object or null if no such column in this column model
     */
    public TableColumn getColumnByModelIndex(int modelColumnIndex) {
        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < allTableColumns.size(); ++columnIndex) {
            TableColumn column = (TableColumn) allTableColumns.get(columnIndex);
            if (column.getModelIndex() == modelColumnIndex) {
                return column;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /** Checks wether the specified column is currently visible.
     * @param aColumn column to check
     * @return visibility of specified column (false if there is no such column at all. [It's not visible, right?])
     */
    public boolean isColumnVisible(TableColumn aColumn) {
        return (tableColumns.indexOf(aColumn) >= 0);
    }

    /** Append <code>column</code> to the right of exisiting columns.
     * Posts <code>columnAdded</code> event.
     * @param column The column to be added
     * @see #removeColumn
     * @exception IllegalArgumentException if <code>column</code> is <code>null</code>
     */
    public void addColumn(TableColumn column) {
        allTableColumns.add(column);
        super.addColumn(column);
    }

    /** Removes <code>column</code> from this column model.
     * Posts <code>columnRemoved</code> event.
     * Will do nothing if the column is not in this model.
     * @param column the column to be added
     * @see #addColumn
     */
    public void removeColumn(TableColumn column) {
        int allColumnsIndex = allTableColumns.indexOf(column);
        if (allColumnsIndex != -1) {
            allTableColumns.remove(allColumnsIndex);
        }
        super.removeColumn(column);
    }

    /** Moves the column from <code>oldIndex</code> to <code>newIndex</code>.
     * Posts  <code>columnMoved</code> event.
     * Will not move any columns if <code>oldIndex</code> equals <code>newIndex</code>.
     *
     * @param    oldIndex            index of column to be moved
     * @param    newIndex            new index of the column
     * @exception IllegalArgumentException    if either <code>oldIndex</code> or
     *                         <code>newIndex</code>
     *                        are not in [0, getColumnCount() - 1]
     */
    public void moveColumn(int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
        if ((oldIndex < 0) || (oldIndex >= getColumnCount())
                || (newIndex < 0) || (newIndex >= getColumnCount())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("moveColumn() - Index out of range");
        }

        TableColumn fromColumn = (TableColumn) tableColumns.get(oldIndex);
        TableColumn toColumn = (TableColumn) tableColumns.get(newIndex);

        int allColumnsOldIndex = allTableColumns.indexOf(fromColumn);
        int allColumnsNewIndex = allTableColumns.indexOf(toColumn);

        if (oldIndex != newIndex) {
            allTableColumns.remove(allColumnsOldIndex);
            allTableColumns.add(allColumnsNewIndex, fromColumn);
        }

        super.moveColumn(oldIndex, newIndex);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the total number of columns in this model.
     *
     * @param   onlyVisible   if set only visible columns will be counted
     * @return    the number of columns in the <code>tableColumns</code> array
     * @see    #getColumns
     */
    public int getColumnCount(boolean onlyVisible) {
        List<TableColumn> columns = (onlyVisible ? tableColumns : allTableColumns);
        return columns.size();
    }

    /**
     * Returns an <code>Enumeration</code> of all the columns in the model.
     *
     * @param   onlyVisible   if set all invisible columns will be missing from the enumeration.
     * @return an <code>Enumeration</code> of the columns in the model
     */
    public Iterator<TableColumn> getColumns(boolean onlyVisible) {

        List<TableColumn> columns = (onlyVisible ? tableColumns : allTableColumns);
        return columns.iterator();

    }

    /**
     * Returns the position of the first column whose identifier equals <code>identifier</code>.
     * Position is the the index in all visible columns if <code>onlyVisible</code> is true or
     * else the index in all columns.
     *
     * @param    identifier   the identifier object to search for
     * @param    onlyVisible  if set searches only visible columns
     *
     * @return        the index of the first column whose identifier
     *            equals <code>identifier</code>
     *
     * @exception       IllegalArgumentException  if <code>identifier</code>
     *                is <code>null</code>, or if no
     *                <code>TableColumn</code> has this
     *                <code>identifier</code>
     * @see        #getColumn
     */
    public int getColumnIndex(Object identifier, boolean onlyVisible) {
        if (identifier == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Identifier is null");
        }

        List columns = (onlyVisible ? tableColumns : allTableColumns);
        int noColumns = columns.size();
        TableColumn column;

        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < noColumns; ++columnIndex) {
            column = (TableColumn) columns.get(columnIndex);

            if (identifier.equals(column.getIdentifier())) {
                return columnIndex;
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Identifier not found");
    }

    /**
     * Returns the <code>TableColumn</code> object for the column
     * at <code>columnIndex</code>.
     *
     * @param    columnIndex    the index of the column desired
     * @param    onlyVisible    if set columnIndex is meant to be relative to all visible columns only
     *                          else it is the index in all columns
     *
     * @return    the <code>TableColumn</code> object for the column
     *                at <code>columnIndex</code>
     */
    public TableColumn getColumn(int columnIndex, boolean onlyVisible) {
        return (TableColumn) tableColumns.elementAt(columnIndex);
    }

    /**
     * Returns all the columns
     * @return
     */
    public TableColumn[] getAllColumns() {

        return allTableColumns.toArray(new TableColumn[allTableColumns.size()]);

    }

    public TableColumn[] getHiddenColumns() {

        ArrayList<TableColumn> lstColumns = new ArrayList<TableColumn>(10);

        for (TableColumn column : getAllColumns()) {

            if (!isColumnVisible(column)) {

                lstColumns.add(column);

            }

        }

        return lstColumns.toArray(new TableColumn[lstColumns.size()]);

    }

}
```

Comment: MadProgrammer: Thank you so much for your help sir! I replaced all of my code with what you said but it still isn't working 100% right. Here is a new pic to show you what I mean. I have also edited my code in my first post so please take a look at it again. http://i48.tinypic.com/2rzpfe9.jpg

Comment: Ahhh, so you want the columns to be removed as well. What should happen if a value appears in both columns?

Comment: If a value appears in both columns, then both columns should stay. But if a value appears on only ONE column, the other column obviously doesn't need to be there. Thanks again sir!

Comment: Could someone please help me to fix the issue that I'm having? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have 3 month old who is teething, trust me, I'd prefer to be working on your problem :P

Comment: Sorry, I just thought that maybe you had forgotten or something. Definitely take care of your kid first, my problem can wait. :)

Comment: Okay, so I had lots of time to think about this (trust me on that) and I think this will meet your needs better

Comment: Awesome, I will give this a try tonight when I get home and will let you know how it goes.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry to keep you waiting but I haven't been home in the three days due to traveling. I will be home this weekend. Thanks again for your hard work!