# How to show/hide certain JTable columns based on selection in JComboBox

Tags: swing, jtable, hidden, visible

I have a `JTable` and a `JComboBox`. I want certain columns to hide when I select one item in the combobox and the same hidden columns to reappear when I select the other item in the combobox. I write,

```
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(8).setMinWidth(0)
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(8).setMaxWidth(0)
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(8).setWidth(0)
```

for hiding the column, but when I again write

```
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(8).setMinWidth(100)
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(8).setMaxWidth(100)
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(8).setWidth(100)
```

the hidden columns do not become visible.

Comment: See also this related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10089138/230513).

Comment: but whats a problem in above code???

Answer (score 1):

Reason is that both setMin/setMax enforce the relation

```
min <= width <= max
```

That is the order of method calling matters

```
// hiding
column.setMinWidth(0);
column.setMaxWidth(0);

// showing
column.setMaxWidth(100);
column.setMinWidth(100);
```

Note that you need not call setWidth, that's handled internally.

That said: forcing the sizes is .. a hack. Consider using a clean solution, f.i. a framework like [SwingX](http://swingx.java.net) which has (amongst other niceties :-) full-fledged support for column hiding

Comment: You know I am a fan of `SwingX`, but column hiding is part of the JDK as well. `JTable#removeColumn` removes the column from the view side only, not from the model side

Comment: @Robin yeah, I know :-) The part that requires some more thought (than hiding) is to show it again at the expected position. Not rocket science of course, but nice-to-have without needing to worry about the boring details.

Answer (score 1):

Use `JTable#removeColumn` and `JTable#addColumn`. These operations only affect the view side, not the model side

Answer (score 1):

> *what's a problem in above code*?

In addition to kleopatra's helpful [insight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12996788/230513), documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumn.html#setMinWidth%28int%29), some L&Fs are more or less cooperative. For example, `com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel` always leaves enough width to drag after `setMinWidth(0)`, although the column can be forced to zero width manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(8).setMinWidth(100)
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(8).setMaxWidth(100)
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(8).setWidth(100)
}
```

The columns will become visible.