# Problems with copy value TableColumn invisible

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecolumn

To hide (make invisible) TableColumns normally do:

```
TableColumn.setMinWidth(0);
TableColumn.setMaxWidth(0);
```

or remove from the model with removeColumn method (column);

But at run time we have the need to leave invisible or visible the column and ends up being more practical to use **setMinWidth (0) and setMaxWidth (0)**.

This creates a problem because if the user selects a table row and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and **paste** it into a text file,  it can copy the value of the hidden column!!!

We could to solve the problem using [TransferHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/TransferHandler.html) to not perform CopyAction of JComponent. How TableColumn is not a JComponent would not give to solve this way.

Another alternative would be to define: (JTable to disallow selection lines)

```
JTable.setRowSelectionAllowed(false)
```

Well this last solution would not be feasible for me because I need to keep the permit selection of rows in the table. Does anyone have another solution to restrict copying of values ​​from all the columns?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

> To hide (make invisible) TableColumns normally do:

```
TableColumn.setMinWidth(0);
TableColumn.setMaxWidth(0);
```

- [this isn't good way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10089138/714968), playing with zero size, this column isn't hiddenonly has un_natural size, still is accesible for all mouse & key events
- you have to `removeColumn()` from `JTable`s view

Comment: Thanks for the reply
You know what it would prevent the copying action even for the visible columns?